# How to get value from Promise Object Type in Angular?

Tags: angular, promise

I have defined a function call in Angular Service:

```
getNewJoinerInfo(staffID: String) {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.ldapEndPoint + staffID, this.httpOptions).toPromise()
               .then(res => of(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)).result[0] as NewJoinerObj))
}
```

When I call this function in a component, how can I get those values from `Promise<NewJoinerObj>` type? As I try to assign the return to `NewJoinerObj` type it's wrong as `Promise<NewJoinerObj>` is not `NewJoinerObj`.

```
var response = <NewJoinerObj> this.newJoinerService.getNewJoinerInfo(this.newJoiner.staffId);
```

What shall I do?

Comment: I recommend you read up on how to work with promises in JS and Angular. They represent asynchronous values (that may not be populated yet), so you can't just cast an asynchronous value to a synchronous one.

You should also look into using the `async / await` syntax, which simplifies working with promises, and the `async` pipe in Angular allows you to "unwrap" the promise in the view code, but not within the component code.

Comment: Thanks @GregL, in my case I would like to enforce synchronous API call, and in my code, if I remove <NewJoinerObj> I can see those response JSON content in Promise<NewJoinerObj> debugging in console log, just no idea how to consume those data in component.

Comment: Synchronous API calls are not a good idea and [officially deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request). I request that you rethink that requirement and instead learn how to work with asynchronous data in JS and Angular.

Answer (score 1):

You are using angular.

> Using Promises in angular is not recommended

Lets consider the below code

```typescript
getNewJoinerInfo = (staffID: String) => 
  this.httpClient.get(this.ldapEndPoint + staffID, this.httpOptions)
```

I simply return the response. This will return an `Observable<Object>`.
Lets consider your code,

You call `.toPromise()` - This converts to `Promise` 
You call the `.then()` and return `of()` which converts back to `Observable`

You could have achieved this by simply piping the `Observable` stream

```typescript
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getNewJoinerInfo = (staffID: String) => 
  this.httpClient.get(this.ldapEndPoint + staffID, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    map(([result]) => result as NewJoinerObj )
  )
```

I have used **destructuring** to extract the first item i.e instead of `map((result) => result[0] )` I have `map(([result]) => result )`

The next thing to note is that you need to subscribe to the `Observable`. Look at it like the `.then()` of `Observables`.

In your component you can have

```typescript
newjoiner: NewJoinerObj;

ngOnInit () {
this.myService.getNewJoinerInfo().subscribe(
    res => this.newjoiner = res
  )
}
```

And in your html simply bind

```html
<span>{{ newjoiner | json }}</span>
```

The `json` **pipe** simply enables display of JSON object